# Нажать программно кнопку мыши средствами C#

Tags: c#, wpf, эмулятор

Подскажите решение. Требуется программно нажать кнопку мыши, затем кнопку клавиатуры в приложении WPF без использования сторонних API. Импорт библиотеки `user32.dll` не предлагать. 
[Здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms171548(v=vs.110).aspx) нашел частичное решение проблемы, но там предупреждение что метод работает по-разному в версиях Windows.
Прошу пример для нажатия кнопки мыши и клавиатуры.

Нашел пример как это можно сделать, запускается но не кликает

```
 public void imitianionDoubleRight()
 {
      var temp = new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs(System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right, 2, 630, 630, 0);

      button1_MouseClick(null, temp);
 }

 private void button1_MouseClick(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
 {
 }
```

Comment: user32.dll чем не угодил?

Comment: Хочется использовать чистый шарп, без солянки из сторонних библиотек.

Comment: @ДжимМакФлай, эмуляция нажатий клавиш происходит на уровне ОС.  По этому на чистом шарпе этого сделать не получится. В любом случае всё сводится к использованию сторонних библиотек.

Comment: user32.dll — это системная библиотека. Не бывает Windows без этой библиотеки.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте использовать `System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys`:

```
SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
```

Подробнее можно узнать на [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys(v=vs.110).aspx)

Но под капотом там так же используется `user32.dll`, если я не ошибаюсь

**UDP**

Вот есть [пример](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.uitesting.mouse.aspx) нажатия на мышь без явного использования сторонних библиотек

Comment: Это вроде встроенные в студию элементы для тестирования. Будет ли программа потом работать на других компах корректно? Можно чуть более подробный пример для нажатия кнопки мыши? Мое владение шарпом на уровне студента.

Comment: @ДжимМакФлай, только через `user32.dll`. Есть хороший [пример](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416748/how-to-simulate-mouse-click-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

Без `user32.dll` никуда, потому что все действия связаные с вводом мышки и клавиатуры на Windows сводится к `user32.dll`. Даже WPF где-то у себя в недрах использует `user32.dll`, для генераций событий связаные с мышкой и клавиатурой.

А для эмуляции ввода с мыши и клавиатуры используйте [InputSimulator](https://www.nuget.org/packages/InputSimulator/), но эта библиотека тоже где-то у себя внутри использует `user32.dll`.

**Example: Single key press**

```
public void PressTheSpacebar()
{
  InputSimulator.SimulateKeyPress(VirtualKeyCode.SPACE);
}
```

**Example: Key-down and Key-up**

```
public void ShoutHello()
{
  // Simulate each key stroke
  InputSimulator.SimulateKeyDown(VirtualKeyCode.SHIFT);
  InputSimulator.SimulateKeyPress(VirtualKeyCode.VK_H);
  InputSimulator.SimulateKeyPress(VirtualKeyCode.VK_E);
  InputSimulator.SimulateKeyPress(VirtualKeyCode.VK_L);
  InputSimulator.SimulateKeyPress(VirtualKeyCode.VK_L);
  InputSimulator.SimulateKeyPress(VirtualKeyCode.VK_O);
  InputSimulator.SimulateKeyPress(VirtualKeyCode.VK_1);
  InputSimulator.SimulateKeyUp(VirtualKeyCode.SHIFT);

  // Alternatively you can simulate text entry to acheive the same end result
  InputSimulator.SimulateTextEntry("HELLO!");
}
```

[Здесь](https://inputsimulator.codeplex.com) больше примеров.

Comment: С эмуляцией мыши всё получилось. К сожалению эмуляция ввода с клавиатуры работает в обычных приложениях, но в играх нет. пробовал посмотреть в сторону XNA точнее Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Keyboard но нашел только как считывать нажатые клавиши, а мне требуется их нажать. Нагуглил что это можно делать через DirectInput, но там поддержка прекратилась еще в 200х, хочется использовать более актуальную библиотеку. Кто-нибудь может подсказать по поводу XNA или другого решения?